# How to Update Datatable automatically after dialog box is closed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have two JS files in which one is main JS file for parent page which contains Datatable which gets populated through ajax call. And other one is specifically for update functionality in which function is defined to update required values into database. That update is done in dialog box. So after successful update sweet alert comes which shows product is successfully updated. So what I want is updated values should be immediately reflected in Datatable of Parent Page. Currently it is showing old value only untill I refresh my page manually. Below are both JS files. And I am new in Javascript and Jquery. So Please help

```
var oTable;
var url_data_source;
(function(window, undefined) {
    window.lastQuery = null;
    function initDataSource(after_id) {
        url_data_source = '/event/productlocation/ajax?action=data_source';
        oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": url_data_source,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "iCookieDuration": 60*60*24,
            "sCookiePrefix": "tkpd_datatable_",
            "sPaginationType": "simple",
            "scrollX": true,
            "aaSorting": [ [0,'desc'] ],
            "iDisplayLength": 20,
            "aLengthMenu": [[20, 40, 60, 80, 100], [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sInfoFiltered": "",
                "sProcessing": " "
            },

            "aoColumns": [
                { "sName": "id", "mDataProp": "id"},
                { "sName": "location_id", "mDataProp": "location_id"},
                { "sName": "product_id", "mDataProp": "product_id"},
                { "sName": "status_str", "mDataProp": "status_str"},
                { "sName": "actions", "mDataProp": "actions"},
            ],
            "fnDrawCallback":function(){
            },
            "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                $("#datatable_paginate").on("click", "#datatable_next", function(){
                    var after_id = ""
                    url_data_source = '/event/productlocation/ajax?action=data_source';
                    after_id_url = $("#after_id_url").val();
                    after_id = after_id_url.split("after_id=")

                    url_data_source += "&after_id="+after_id[1]; 
                    redraw();
                });
            },
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                aoData.push( {"name": "email", "value": $('#search_email').val()} );

                if (after_id != "") {
                    aoData.push( {"name": "after_id", "value": after_id} );
                }

                if ($('#search_id_product').val()) {        
                    aoData.push( {"name": "product_id", "value": $('#search_id_product').val()} );      
                }

                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": url_data_source,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": function(result) {
                        var message_error = result.message_error
                        if (message_error) {
                            $('#datatable_processing').css("visibility","hidden");
                            swal({ title: message_error, type: "error"});
                        } else if (result.status == "OK") {
                            result.data = formatingDatatable(result.data)
                            fnCallback(result)
                            lastQuery = aoData;
                        } else {
                            $('#datatable_processing').css("visibility","hidden");
                            swal({ title: "Tidak ada hasil", type: "info"});
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        swal({ title: manager.getAjaxError(XMLHttpRequest), type: "error"});
                        $('#datatable_processing').css("visibility","hidden");
                        $('.load__overlay').hide();
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#datatable_processing').css("visibility","visible");
                        $('.load__overlay').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('#datatable_processing').css("visibility","hidden");
                        $('.load__overlay').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function redraw() {
        $("#datatable").dataTable().fnClearTable();
    }
    function formatingDatatable(events) {
        var result = [];
        var uri_next;
        $.each(events.location_products, function(i, productlocation) {
            result.push({
                id: productlocation.id,
                location_id: productlocation.location_id,
                product_id: productlocation.product_id,
                status_str: productlocation.status_str,
                actions:'<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light m-b-5 btn-sm m-r-5 btn-sm detail-productlocation" data-target="#modal-event-productlocation-detail" data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + productlocation.id + '" product-id="' + productlocation.product_id + '" location-id="' + productlocation.location_id + '" status-str="' + productlocation.status_str + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Details</button>'
            });
        })
        $("#after_id_url").val(events.page.uri_next)
        uri_next = events.page.uri_next
        result.after_id_url = uri_next
        return result
    }   

    function initFilter() {
        $("#filter-form").submit(function() {
            url_data_source = '/event/productlocation/ajax?action=data_source';
            if(oTable == null){
                initDataSource("");
            } else {
                oTable.fnDraw();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    $('#datatable_paginate').on('click', '#datatable_next', function() {
        initDataSource("");
    })

    $('#datatable').on('click', '.detail-productlocation', function() {
        $('.load__overlay').show();
        $("#modal-event-productlocation-detail").remove();
        $(this).removeAttr("data-target", "#modal-event-productlocation-detail");
        $(this).removeAttr("data-toggle", "modal");
        //var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var dt = {
            "id": $(this).attr("data-id"),
            "product_id": $(this).attr("product-id"),
            "location_id": $(this).attr("location-id"),
            "status": $(this).attr("status-str"),
        }

        $.ajax({
            "url": '/event/productlocation/ajax?action=show_dialog_details',
            "type": 'GET',
            "data": dt,
            success: function (result) {
                $('.load__overlay').hide();
                $("body").append(result);
                $(this).attr("data-target", "#modal-event-productlocation-detail");
                $(this).attr("data-toggle", "modal");
                $('#modal-event-productlocation-detail').modal('show');
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('.load__overlay').hide();
                swal({ title: manager.getAjaxError(XMLHttpRequest), type: "error", });
            },
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //initDate();
        initFilter();
        //initCategoryList();
        var after_id = "";
        initDataSource(after_id);
    });

})(window);
```

event-productlocation-update.js

```
    function sendProductLocationData() {
        var jsonData = {};

        var formFields = $(":input");
        jQuery.each(formFields, function(i, field) { //Accessing all the element of form and get Key and Value
            var key = field.name; //Keyname of each Field
            var elementid = field.id; //Id of each Field
            elementid = "#" + elementid;
            var value = $(elementid).val();

            jsonData[key] = parseInt(value);
            if (key == "status") {
                if ($("#event_checkbox_status").is(':checked') == true) {
                    jsonData.status = 1;
                } else {
                    jsonData.status = 0;
                }
            }
        });

        productlocationdetail = JSON.stringify(jsonData); //Creating json Object

        $.ajax({
            url: '/update/product/productlocation',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: productlocationdetail,
            "success": function(result) {
                var message_error = result.message_error
                if (message_error) {
                    $('#modal-event-productlocation-detail').css("visibility", "hidden")
                    swal({
                        title: message_error,
                        type: "error"
                    });
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                } else {
                    $('#modal-event-productlocation-detail').css("visibility", "hidden")
                    swal({
                        title: "Product Location Updated Successfully",
                        type: "info"
                    });
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                swal({
                    title: manager.getAjaxError(XMLHttpRequest),
                    type: "error"
                });
                $('#modal-event-productlocation-detail').css("visibility", "hidden")
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $('.load__overlay').hide();
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#modal-event-productlocation-detail').css("visibility", "visible")
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            },
            complete: function() {
                swal({
                    title: "Product Location Updated Successfully",
                    type: "info"
                });
                $('#modal-event-productlocation-detail').css("visibility", "hidden")
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                $('.load__overlay').hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way you could handle this.

One way you could handle this is to store the item/s in a variable in a jSON array.

When get confirmation back from the server that that the the update was successful you could then create function to update the dataTable with with this function.

```
function updateDataTable(dataTableObj,jsonArray)
     /*
        Clears and populates the dataTable with JSON array
     */
    dataTableObj.clear();
    jsonArray.forEach(function(row){

            dataTableObj.row.add(row);



    });
    dataTableObj.draw();
}
```

The other way you could update the table is to create a route on your server that sends the jsonArray but this requires an additional request to the server.
*Note: If you use the Ajax call be sure to invoke the function inside the the ajax callback function*